# How to do double jump with phaser

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine, phaser-framework

I would like to know how to do a double jump with phaser.

```
this.jumpCount = 0;
this.jumpkey = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.UP);
this.jumpkey.onDown.add(jumpCheck, this); 

jumpCheck = function(){
   if (player.jumpCount < 2){
      player.jump();
      player.jumpCount ++;
   }
}
```

I've tried this, but it didn't work and I don't really understand what the word `this.` stand for.

EDIT: Ok, I've been trying to solve this by myself but I don't know what to do.

Here is my new code. It can double jump but my player can "fly" with triple, quadruple, etc jump and I really don't know why.
Could you help me ?

```
//jump
    var jumpCount = 0;
    var jumpKey = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.UP);
    jumpKey.onDown.add(jumpCheck);

    function jumpCheck() {
        if((jumpCount < 1) && (player.body.touching.down)){
            jump1();
            console.log("jumpCount =" + jumpCount);
            console.log("Vitesse ="+ player.body.velocity.y);
            //  attention, remettre jumpCount à zéro si on touche le sol
//          if(player.body.touching.down){
//              jumpCount = 0;
//          }
        }

    //double jump
        if((jumpCount < 2) && (!player.body.touching.down)){
            jump2();
            console.log("jumpCount =" + jumpCount);
            console.log("Vitesse ="+ player.body.velocity.y);

        }

    }

    function jump1(){
        console.log("jump1");
        jumpCount ++;
        player.body.velocity.y = -250;
    }

    function jump2(){
        console.log("jump2");
        jumpCount ++;
        player.body.velocity.y = -150;

    }
```

The chrome console always send me jumpCount = 1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really create a function if you're not calling it either a function or putting var in front of it. So that means you could change it at least to this:

```
var jumpCheck = function() { /*jumping code*/ };
```

Then to explain 'this'. 'this' is a bit hard to explain, it's easier to start understanding it by using it. It refers in your case(and most cases) to a variable inside an object. Let's say we have this code:

```
var x, y;

function Location(x, y) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
};
```

What I just created there are two global variables and one function which we can simply turn into an object using:

```
var point = new Location(100, 100);

//and I will change the global variables as well.
x = 200; y = 150;
```

This is where this comes to show, say I want to change the x of point. However, we just changed the global x, so how can this be done? Simple, by calling it from inside the object, and this makes sure it only changes inside that object.

```
point.x = 150;

//this makes sure that x = 200; point.x = 150;
```

If I were to make more Objects

```
var point2 = new Location(300, 200);
```

Doesn't change the variable x inside the point object.
So what does it do in your example? It binds jumpCount to the player object meaning it can only be changed by specifically calling player.jumpCount. As I said, it is quite hard to understand but this should at least make sure you know the basics of this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample program to [**Double Jump**](http://gamemechanicexplorer.com/#platformer-5)